# azure kubernetes network policy to allow some external hosts only for a pod

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say I've created a cluster with a manifest like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
        use_db: "true"
        backend: "true"
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: <...>
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: <...>
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

I've activated the network plugin and network policies. It's working well. But I want to set up some network policies. I found many examples how to manage traffic between pods, how to allow external traffic and traffic from all internal pods. But I can't understand how to be in my case. That's what I want:

- Deny traffic between all pods inside kubernetes by default (I can do it).
- Allow external traffic to the pods labeled **backend** from some external subnet to port 80 (but not from internal pods)
- Allow external traffic exchange with some database (I know it's dns name and port) for pods with the label **use_db**

Please, can some body give an example of the network policy yaml file for this case?